# POSTing json to API with Angular 2/4

Tags: json, angular, rest, api

I am new to angular 4 and REST API development. I have developed a Login API in back-end and it works fine when I call it using Postman:

[image]

In the front-end application which is an Angular 4 project, I have created a service to call this login API. Here is the method I created in this service:

```
sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate/user';
    const body = '{"username": "' + username + '", "password": "' + password + '"}';
    const headers = new Headers(
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
    return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers});
}
```

My first question is:
**Is this the correct way to pass the json object and call this API?**

And I also created a component which calls the method in the service. Here is the method/event-handler I created in this component:

```
onSubmit(uname: string, pwd: string) {
    this.loginService.sendCredential(uname, pwd).subscribe(
        res => {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', 'true');
            location.reload();
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

My second question is:
**How should I check whether a token is returned back or an error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1:

You do not need to stringify the body object when you do a `http.post()` in angular. Just use a normal object will do, and the `Http` class will help you parse it internally:

```
sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate/user';
    //do not need to stringify your body
    const body = {
        username, password
    }
    const headers = new Headers(
        {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
    return this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers});
}
```

#### Question 2:

As for your error, note that Angular also catch every `http` error. and by http error, it means that any status code that is `<200` or `>=300` will be an error. So only status codes that is in between 200 and 300 is considered successful. Upon an error received, angular will throw an `Observable` error, which you will need to handle explicitly (which you did it correctly):

```
onSubmit(uname: string, pwd: string) {
    this.loginService.sendCredential(uname, pwd).subscribe(
        res => {
            //token should be in your res object
            this.loggedIn = true;
            localStorage.setItem('PortalAdminHasLoggedIn', 'true');
            location.reload();
        },
        err => {
            //handle your error here.
            //there shouldn't be any token here
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

With your above code, you should receive your token in your successful callback, and it will be in the `res` object. If there's an error, no token should be received and you should handle the error at the error callback.

Comment: I just get "Argument of type { headers: headers } is not assignable to parameter of type RequestOptionArgs | undefined" etc.

Comment: I now imported headers, but get NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Headers is not defined
ReferenceError: Headers is not defined

Comment: That is, import { Headers } from '@angular/http